# STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered

Tags: c++, c, buffer-overrun

I have searched for this particular error and found the underlying issue involves loop counts being wrong and causing the program to exceed it's bounds for the array.

However, after I lowered each array to the point where the array began to lose data on output, it continued to throw the same error. I am still new to C/C++ but any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

The program seems to run through to the very end and even returns to the main method.

```
#include <stdio.h>



void sortAr(char[]);

    int main ()
{
    char a='y';
    char b,i;
    char c[20];
    int x=0,n=0,z=0;
    while (x<=19)
    {
        c[x]='@'; 
        x++;
    }

    printf("Enter 20 letters: \n"); 

    while (z<=20) //(The '=' caused my problem, removed and it runs fine.)
    {
        z++;
        x=0;
        b='y';
        scanf("%c",&i);
        while (x<=19)
        {
            if (c[x]==i)
                b='n';
            x++;
        }

        if (b=='y')
        {
            c[n]=i;
            n++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The nonduplicate values are: \n");      

    sortAr(c);

}





    void sortAr(char ar[])
    {
        char z;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) 
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j <= 19; ++j)
        {
            if (ar[i]>ar[j])
            {
                z =  ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[j];
                ar[j] = z;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        if(ar[i]=='@')
            continue;
        printf("%c ", ar[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: You didn't reset `x` before the 2nd use.

Comment: Ah yes, I did forget to add that back in after testing pointers and character arrays for storing values. I went ahead and removed the following         z=20;

    while (x<=19)
    {
        if (c[x]=='@')
        z--;    
        x++;
    }

Comment: I recommend you inspecting your code with a debugger stepping through line by line. That's probably faster than posting it here, and expect others to do so for you.

Comment: Debugger confirmed it hits the end of the main method before the program crashes. It had no issues with the nested for loops so I'm still not too certain what this means for the program, is there anything that might cause a buffer to overrun on program exit?

Comment: @Kal the overrun occured BEFORE program exit and corrupted the return address.

Comment: @Cool Guy when J==20 J>19 which means it wont execute the for loop so i will simply end it's round. Also, I found the error at while (z<=20) I know arrays are supposed to have null characters at the end could this have caused that character to be overwritten, resulting in the program writing to memory not allocated to the array?

Comment: @Kal , Oops. Sorry...

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for that hint by the way I'll admit I didn't understand exactly what you meant by "the return being corrupted" but after running back through the main block I see how you came to that conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error at:

```
while (z<=20)
```

The reason is the array would overwrite more characters than intended by executing more times than the array had indexed in the memory. As a result it wrote into memory that was not allocated to it and caused the Stack_Buffer_Overrun.

```
Trace Z:

Z was initialized to 0.
Array was initialized to 20.

While loop starts with Z as the counter for read-ins.
z=0 array=1 1st run,
z=1 array=2 2nd run,
z=2 array=3 3rd run,
z=3 array=4 4th run,
...
z=20 array=21 21st run. (Array cannot hold 21st character and results in Stack_Buffer_Overrun.)
```

Solution:

```
change while(z<=20) -> while(z<20)
```